# Добавление изображений в базу данных и их вывод

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте!

Есть проблема. Нужно в административной панели реализовать функционал, так чтобы я мог загружать большое количество изображений и мог менять порядок их вывода, допустим, хочу чтобы второе изображение стало первым и так далее. Это очень удобно!

Подскажите пожалуйста, может уже есть готовые решение. Очень нужно, а как это сделать понятия не имею... В продолжении темы, не знал как вставить код просто. Сделал загрузку изображения, но мне нужно чтобы она была зациклена, так как изображений я могу выбрать от 3 до 20 и более. Мне нужно чтобы в таблице добавлялось все как новая запись. По коду думаю будет ясно.

> ```
> if (isset($_POST['add_project_submit_rus'])){
>     // Add project
>     foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k) {
>       if (!$_FILES['file']['error'][$k]) {
>         if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k])) {
>           if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$k], "../uploads/project/".$_FILES['file']['name'][$k])) {
>             $img = $_FILES['file']['name'][];
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
> ```

```
    $url = "".$domain."/uploads/product/".$img;
    R::exec("INSERT INTO testimage (`id`, `url`, `view`, `index`, `top`, `post_id`) VALUES (NULL, '".$url."', '0', '1', '0', '0');");
    // Add project
    echo "<script>alert('Товар додано!');</script>";
    // header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: честно пытался понять, чего вы хотите добиться и чего у вас не получается, но не смог

Comment: короче говоря. Нужно чтобы он загружал изображения в базу по одной строке чтобы у каждого изображения был свой индекс сортировки.

Comment: Вот загрузил допустим я 15 изображений, значит +15 записей в базе и напротив каждого свой индекс должен быть. Что такое индекс - индекс это тот порядок по которому я хочу выводить изображения на странице сайта.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста помочь мне, очень срочно нужно

Comment: ну и в чем проблема? Добавляете в БД столбец типа INT и пишите в него порядковый номер

Comment: я так и сделал, только вот скрипт сохраняет только одну фотографию в базу в место того количества, что я выбрал.

Comment: так внесите второй кусок кода внутрь цикла, сразу после `$img = $_FILES['file']['name'][];`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61352/discussion-between-cyberx-and-rjhdby).